# Document type and browser behaviour espesially MS IE 10

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, dtd

Is it worth to check a page if IExplorer does not work correctly?

Story: I mix HTML and SVG. I started with a some how low aproach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html [
 <!ENTITY duration "3s">
 ...
 ]>
<html>
<!-- all elements in principle valid (open close)
just not shown here -->
...
<svg ....>
...
</svg>
<p> ...</p>
...
</html>
```

And - surpise - 3 of 4 browser took this and displayed it like I wanted. IE10 - not

So I use W3C validator to check this code, and got (as expected) a rally bad testimonial. So I put time into learning about DTD. And ended up with a code like this, that is **W3C** - **valid**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0 plus SVG 1.1//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/2002/04/xhtml-math-svg/xhtml-math-svg.dtd" [
 <!ENTITY duration "3s">
]>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>   
...
<svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  ...>
 <svg:defs> ... <svg:defs>
</svg:svg>
...
```

I got now a valid page (*happy I am*), but IE10 still does not display how it should (other 3 - at least - still showing what I expect, but the "think longer" )

So my Question:

Is it worth using this - valid and probably hyper correct aproach, if MS seems to ignore it? Or is my page still wrong?

[the page that I am talking about](http://keepitsimple-soft.com/logo.xml)

Edit: I forgott to tell; the SVG should be animated, an react on mouseover

Edit #2: [the W3C helping putting all together](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-XHTMLplusMathMLplusSVG-20020809/#dtd)

Comment: If you hit F12,in which mode is you page running?

Comment: I hit F12 and get Browsermodus: IE10

Comment: Wow, a real xml based XHTML page; one doesn't see that often. Upvoting. Anyway, have you checked what IE does without the &entities;?

Comment: But to answer your question; in general, it's better to have a page that validates fully than to have a faulty one. Different browsers respond differently to errors! So, given that the other browsers still display it the way you want, I'd say leave it the way it is. And if there are ways to make it work in all browsers, I'm sure some of these ways validate.

Comment: Thx for the "wow" and - no - removing the entities does not change IE10s mood. [entity less variant](http://keepitsimple-soft.com/stacknco/logo2.xml)

Comment: Sure! you are right, its better to have a 'valid' page. It was just a bit frustrating, that one of the self called leading browser seems to be wrong ...

Comment: @halfbit That's a shame; I thought that maybe those entities were what broke IE. Not sure what to suggest now.

Comment: @Lister: I use an other browser :-D

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support svg declarative animation (the animate element and so on).

You can drop in a small js library to make it work similarly to the other browsers, see [FakeSmile with IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459460/fakesmile-with-ie9).