# Dynamic Animation for SVG Elements is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, smil, fakesmile

I'm trying to do SVG element's animation while dynamically adding DOM elements with jquery.  If I add those elements inside `<body>` as below its working.Working Sample for this is 
http://jsfiddle.net/bZdfH/2/

```
<svg>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="http://leunen.me/fakesmile/smil.user.js"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="20" style="fill: pink; stroke: red;" >
    <animate attributeName="r" dur="4s" values="20; 0; 20" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
 </svg>
```

When I add it dynamically, animation will not start in IE, however it works with Chrome and FireFox.Here is what I have.

```
<svg>
 <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="http://leunen.me/fakesmile/smil.user.js"/>
 <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="20" style="fill: pink; stroke: red;" onmouseover="changeImage(this)" >
 </circle>
</svg>
<script>
    function changeImage(circle) {
      while (circle.firstChild) {
        circle.removeChild(circle.firstChild);
      }
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "blue");
        var animate = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate");
        animate.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "r");
        animate.setAttributeNS(null, "values", "20;0;20");
        animate.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", "6s");
        animate.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "indefinite");
        circle.appendChild(animate);
      }
</script>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pBK4S/) for the Working Sample.Can anyone please help me??

Comment: Maybe this can help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459460/fakesmile-with-ie9

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support SMIL animation.
Source : http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: It is working while creating elements statically.Then why it is not working for dynamic creation of those elements.Any reason??

Comment: Because IE9 and up do support SVG's just not animating them through SMIL animations. (Not sure if I understood u correctly)

Comment: I used SMIL animation in both the fiddles that I mentioned.In IE animation in 1st fiddle is working correctly and not working in 2nd fiddle in which I added DOM elements dynamically.