# SVG and CSS3 Animations not working in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I have this code for animations using HTML5, CSS3 Animations and SVG
`line`. It’s only working in Chrome, Opera and Firefox and not working
in IE and Safari. Any solution?

**Here is the code:**

```css
.line {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#svg path.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 3000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  stroke-width: 2;
  -webkit-animation: lines 5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: lines 5s linear forwards;
  -ms-animation: lines 5s linear forwards;
  -0-animation: lines 5s linear forwards;
  animation: lines 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes lines {
  form {
    stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes lines {
  form {
    stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes lines {
  form {
    stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes lines {
  form {
    stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes lines {
  form {
    stroke-dashoffset: 4000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <svg id="svg" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="1000" id="Layer_1" style="opacity:1;" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 960 560" enable-background="new 0 0 960 560" xml:space="preserve">
    <path class="path" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="1000" stroke-dasharray="11.9901,11.9901" d="M52.652,248.08
      c30.97,37.245,74.957,63.396,122.172,75.244c53.056,13.313,109.816,9.162,161.756-7.968
      c42.308-13.953,83.007-37.533,108.174-74.156c4.655-6.774,8.818-14.153,10.027-22.271c2.24-15.044-6.187-29.969-17.51-40.177
      c-28.483-25.679-73.116-26.422-108.534-11.588c-54.196,22.698-92.323,81.422-86.252,139.649
      c6.07,58.228,59.091,109.265,117.886,109.022c20.716-0.085,41.065-5.884,60.092-14.042c18.307-7.85,35.789-18.023,50.322-31.606
      c14.503-13.555,25.718-30.139,37.837-45.845c17.476-22.649,37.883-44.311,64.254-55.552c26.37-11.241,59.879-9.795,80.612,9.943
      c30.67,29.196,23.317,84.899,56.145,111.668c29.1,23.729,74.437,10.683,102.618-14.121c32.31-28.438,51.374-68.875,65.118-109.573
      c12.464-36.907,21.327-75.103,35.836-111.202" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[See the code in "Code Pen"](http://codepen.io/Mohammed_Moustafa/pen/yeRzpV/)

I want fix it by making it work in IE and Safari. Please, **if possible
in HTML5, CSS and SVG only**.

Comment: @aliasm2k Why you would take HTML5-canvas Out? Please share your opinion?

Comment: I took the tag out as well. There’s no real mention of HTML5 Canvas, you have shared no JS code using the Canvas API, stating “HTML5 only” does not automatically point to Canvas. If you want your solution to be in Canvas, then state it clearly in the question itself and provide JS code of what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Thanks for editing my tags, Yea you right but what about if there is no solution in my code, that is why I said if possible? (it could be in HTML5 Canvas)

Comment: Can you tell me which version of IE you are targeting?

Comment: @Zigma Empire Edge, 10 and 9 but none of them are working, For now I want at least for Edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mozilla Devloper Network - SVG Animation - Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility) says

> Internet Explorer 
>   **Not supported**

Then use FakeSMIL

Refer this [FakeSmile with IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459460/fakesmile-with-ie9)

Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/whyoz/c3wb5sbr/

```
function registerAnimation(anim) {
    var targets = getTargets(anim);
    var elAnimators = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<targets.length ;i++) {
      var target = targets[i];
      var animator = new Animator(anim, target, i);
      animators.push(animator);
      elAnimators[i] = animator;
    }
    anim.animators = elAnimators;
    var id = anim.getAttribute("id");
    if (id)
      id2anim[id] = anim;
    for(var i=0; i<elAnimators.length ;i++)
      elAnimators[i].register();
}

var svg   = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
.......
var animation = document.createElementNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "animate");
.......
.......
registerAnimation(animation);
animation.beginElement();
```

Which could bring animation for SVG in IE

**Refer MSDN** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193979(v=vs.85).aspx

**Example** http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/svg/svgAnimation/basic/06seventeenGearsWith1Button.html